# Voting irregularities is a sin?

Tags: discussion, support, downvotes, unanswered-questions, voting-fraud

I'm not a vampire. I'm a student or learner.

I've posted some questions, which may not be on SO. But, I was fresher to surfing the site. My some questions are still unanswered, and some of these got vote down. These are :

1. [Why does output of printf() in C change; when (“\ n”) is used, instead of (“\n”)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33694700/why-does-output-of-printf-in-c-change-when-n-is-used-instead-of-n)
2. [How the string swapping work in C? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34263731/how-the-string-swapping-work-in-c)
3. [Deleting an arbitrary node in binary min heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34064386/deleting-an-arbitrary-node-in-binary-min-heap)
4. [Does UDP handle congestion explicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33954444/does-udp-handle-congestion-explicitly)
5. [Integral Manchester encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34021655/integral-manchester-encoding)
6. [Handles in the bottom-up parser for string n + n × n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33826077/handles-in-the-bottom-up-parser-for-string-n-n-%C3%97-n)
7. [Does LINE mean SET in set associative cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33970695/does-line-mean-set-in-set-associative-cache)

---

I've edited these questions properly. I'm carefully handling for these questions. But, I'm not receiving answer(s) or upvote, instead of that I've received vote down when I edited these question.

---

Yesterday, I've voted myself only for these more down voted questions, but today these corrected today. :). No problem! In  fact I hate voting myself.

---

In these days, I'm learning some programming language. When I feel to ask some question on SO. I can't! Since, I've got ban to post new query, because of above given questions.

---

My question is :

> Is it possible to recover my SO account?

I knew it is possible with voting myself, but as I'm learning. So, voting myself will be betrayed myself. Please, give your view/solution, thank in advance?

---

EDIT : Thanks for link, but I'm reading that link since last 2 months. In my opinion, this should not be duplicate problem. Whatever, you decide please :).

Comment: You can only vote for yourself from another account. And yes, that is a capital sin. Votes should come from other people. And they should only judge the post, not the person.

Comment: @S.L.Barth, I'm unable to find helping nature! Can you tell me please, why people gave vote down continuously?

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay because people post crap questions continuously.

Comment: Haha.. thanks for link :) . IMO : may not be duplicate. You have freedom to decide anymore, please :).

Comment: Are you not going to edit *this* post as well and add "Edit : You are welcome, before any down-votes, please try to leave comment below, so that I can improve the quality of this post. Thank in advance :)" at the bottom?

Comment: I think that "EDIT:..."(on these questions) implies negative post, right?

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible to recover my SO account?

Yes, by making edits that actually make these questions good, as every time you edit a question it gets bumped to the frontpage (reopen queue if closed).

Answering questions and making good edits also helps, but takes a lot longer.

> I knew it is possible with voting myself, but as I'm learning. So, voting myself will be betrayed myself. Please, give your view/solution, thank in advance?

Voting for yourself is considered a violation of the Stack Overflow terms and conditions and will quickly result in your account being suspended, and the other accounts you used to vote for yourself being destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. 

I've already said truth :  "Yesterday, I've voted myself only for these more down voted questions, but today these corrected today. :). No problem! In fact I hate voting myself."



SO is nice community to learn, I will never violate the rules of SO.

Comment: But I'm regularly receiving vote-down

1.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33970695/does-line-mean-set-in-set-associative-cache

2.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34021655/integral-manchester-encoding

Comment: I'm unable to find helping nature! Can you tell me please, why people gave vote down continuously?

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay, most downvotes are due to violating the rules, or because the question is that simple, that with a little bit of effort, you could have found the answer yourself. One of the questions you linked in your question, is a duplicate. If you searched a bit yourself, you could have found it, and that is why you got downvotes for that one. I see that some of your questions are also straight out of some homework assignment. People tend to downvote those, because those assignments are for you, and not for the SO community.

Comment: @Ivar, yes you are correct. I've mentioned on the post : "I've posted some questions, which should not be on SO. But, I was fresher to surfing the site." Right now , I can't remove my posts to recover my account, right?

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay thats right, deleted posts still count against you.